# NGINX uses SSLv3 despite only TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 specified

Tags: https, nginx, raspbian, letsencrypt

I started to configure my own website recently (no prior experience in servers, but several years in Linux) and I selected NGINX for my webserver. It's running on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian 8 (essentially Debian Jessie). I got regular http working very quickly, but https is a pain in the ass. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04), except for the part about Let's Encrypt, since I used certbot with webroot for getting my certs. Now when I try to connect to the server from a web browser with its domain name or its external IP, I get this:

(I replaced my actual domain name with mywebsite.com)

Chromium:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

mywebsite.com uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

Firefox:

```
Unable to Connect Securely

Firefox cannot guarantee the safety of your data on mywebsite.com because
it uses SSLv3, a broken security protocol.
```

Both of these errors lead me to believe that NGINX is using SSLv3, despite it not being specified in any configuration file. I did not modify `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. There are no syntax errors in the configuration according to `nginx -t`.

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Interestingly, when I connect to the server through its local address, 192.168.1.64, index.html does load but (understandably) browsers complain about the certificates only being valid for mywebsite.com and www.mywebsite.com, not 192.168.1.64.
On my DNS server, I have specified an A record for mywebsite.com and *.mywebsite.com, both directing to the IP of the server. What did I miss?

(moved this question here from Server Fault where it was closed for being off-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me! I forgot to check the port forwarding settings on my ancient modem, so I was reaching its control panel, not my site. I didn't continue from the errors the browsers presented, which I should have done. They really do make that difficult, though.

The only mystery left is why certbot webroot worked in the first place? I thought it needed the port 443 open to do its thing, but I did get the keys to my raspi anyways.